# How to implement a global store in sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

So, I am building an ecommerce app in sveltekit and wanted to implement cart as a global store, so components can query that store for cart status. I pretty much know how to implement it in a single page application, but can't get my head around how to do it with SvelteKit. What will be the best approach to make a reactive cart for such application? Should I store cart at server only and reload cart on each change? or is there a way to implement a global store that works between pages?

Answer (score 1):

Where and how you store the data is a design decision with various considerations: E.g. should it persist when an authenticated user switches devices (e.g. from phone to desktop)? Then you would have to store it on the server.

If the data comes from the server you can probably [load it via the topmost [layout `load` function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data) and put it in a store in a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) which pages get access.

To have a fully client-side global store that does not lose state on (hard) navigation you can wrap `localStorage` or `sessionStoage`, the latter is less permanent. There are libraries that already implement such functionality or you can build your own (the contract for writable stores is very simple: Provide a `subscribe` and `set` function. I give a basic outline of a local storage store e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73438808/546730)).

Comment: Well the cart do comes from server. I want to put it in a store and have it mutated whenever a item is added using a form action.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a global reactive store you can use a reactive db. Like firestore with rxjs (rxfire).

The nice thing is: An RxJS Observable can act as a drop-in replacement to a Svelte store.

Here you can find some [example code](https://fireship.io/lessons/svelte-v3-overview-firebase/). And no need to reload on each change, because it's reactive with the $store syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Just import the store to whatever page needs access to the store. It's entirely global.

```
import { motor } from '../stores.ts';

console.log($motor.horsePower);
```

Comment: Can't do that in sveltekit because global state is shared server-side